# Image Super-resolution by Radial Basis Functions

Tags: python, image, image-processing, interpolation, google-colaboratory

In this project, you will implement the image super-resolution problem. Specifically,
you will start from a digital image of size M*N pixels, and then you will enlarge the
image to (3M) * (3N) pixels. While the pixels in the original image should keep their
original intensities, the intensities of new pixels are interpolated by using a local radial
basis function in a user-chosen neighborhood of each new pixel.

[This is the image I want to enlarge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GVyR.png)

The image is 256 x 256. I want to use Colab and I found a function pysteps.utils.interpolate.rbfinterp2d and here is the documentation for this function:
https://pysteps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pysteps.utils.interpolate.rbfinterp2d.html.

I am very new to computer programming and I am wondering how do I actually do this. I can do individual steps, so I am more or less looking for a (detailed, if possible) outline of steps to accomplish the task. At the end of the project I want to display the original image and then the resulting image after up-scaling it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if that function is suitable for dense image data. Beyond that, you'd use `imageio.imopen()` to read your file into a matrix, then apply the mathematical operation(s), and use `imageio.imwrite()` to write it back.

Comment: May I have more details about these "mathematical operations", please? I know I need to do some linear algebra, but how do I get started? I loaded the image into colab.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a mathematician! You'd probably implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_interpolation :)

Comment: I saw this: https://github.com/JeremyLinux/PyTorch-Radial-Basis-Function-Layer/commit/0cf2ac82e94406a95d9048291edab51410ed41a2?diff=unified 
the other day and thought i might be useful, but I don't know if it is the same type of problem

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Can I be more specific about which bit? Sorry